# What does controls:TextBoxHelper.IsWaitingForData do?

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I have a small WPF application that is using mahapp.metro for styling. There are 7 textboxes in the window with code similar to the examples below. When I run the application, it takes a lot of cpu, more than 90% if possible. When I deleted the controls:TextBoxHelper.IsWaitingForData="True", cpu usage dropped to almost 0% and I have not been able to find any issues. What does the TextBoxHelper.IsWaitingForData really mean?

```
<Canvas Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBox x:Name="SecurityStatusTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding SelectedSecurityStatus, Mode=OneWay}"
                     Margin="50,50,0,0" Height="50" Width="250" FontSize="16"
                     controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True" 
                     controls:TextBoxHelper.IsWaitingForData="True" 
                     controls:TextBoxHelper.UseFloatingWatermark="True" 
                     controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="{x:Static properties:Resources.SecurityStatus}"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="BagTypeTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding SelectedBagType, Mode=OneWay}"
                     Margin="325,50,0,0" Height="50" Width="250" FontSize="16"
                     controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True" 
                     controls:TextBoxHelper.IsWaitingForData="True" 
                     controls:TextBoxHelper.UseFloatingWatermark="True"
                     controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="{x:Static properties:Resources.BagType}"/>
        </Canvas>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `IsWaitingForData` property is set to true an `Effect` is applied to the border of the `TextBox` and animation is applied to the `Opacity` property: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/8a87a1b6ee7376e22930e465e8f3e85f4c5a73bc/src/MahApps.Metro/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.TextBox.xaml

If you pay attention you will see that the `TextBox` gets a slight shadow that fades in and out when the `IsWaitingForData` property is set to true.

If this causes any issues for you should probably just set this property back to `false`.

You may also want to report the issue at GitHub: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues